# How to retrieve Number(Precision,Scale) of an Oracle stored procedure parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Is there any schema/table that describe precision and scale of a Number parameter of a Oracle procedure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view `USER_ARGUMENTS` contains the arguments for your stored procedures (plus `ALL_ARGUMENTS` for those you have access to and `DBA_ARGUMENTS` for every stored procedure/function in the database). The columns `DATA_TYPE`, `DATA_LENGTH`, `DATA_PRECISION`, etc. are what you are looking for.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1014.htm).